# Center text on Canvas?

Tags: text, canvas, javafx-2

Can someone please give me an example on how to center text on a JavaFX 2 [Canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html)?

[GraphicsContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html) has some functions like setTextAlign, but I am not sure on how to use all those methods and which of them I really need. I want to center my text vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Set the text align to center.
2. Set the text baseline to center.
3. Draw the text in the center of your canvas (by positioning it at half the canvas width and height).

Here is a sample:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.canvas.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextCanvas extends Application {
    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(175, 40);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setTextAlign(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        gc.setTextBaseline(VPos.CENTER);
        gc.fillText(
            "Text centered on your Canvas", 
            Math.round(canvas.getWidth()  / 2), 
            Math.round(canvas.getHeight() / 2)
        );

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().addAll(canvas);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

[image: centered text on canvas]

Comment: Thank you jewelsea, works exactly as expected and seeing the sample I now also understand the methods.

Answer (score 0):

you wanna use

```
  control.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); and

  control.setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
```

see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/size_align.htm) for some downloadable sample code of this in action.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately a Canvas and all its content is one complete node, so I fear this won't work.

Comment: I had a rough look at it and my impression is, that this is for positioning nodes in containers, e.g. in a HBox. However a Canvas is not a container / the text in a Canvas is not a Node?